# Using d3 to append colored circles based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG structure like the following:

```
<g class="labels"></g>
```

And some d3 code:

```
// svg is d3 context
var labels = svg.select('.labels');

ca = labels.append('g');

function resize() {
    ca
        .call(colorAxis) // an instance of d3.svg.axis() using same data as below
        .selectAll('text')
            .remove();

    ca
        .selectAll('.tick').select('circle')
            .data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
            .style('fill', function (datum) {
                return '#' + datum.hex;
            })
            .attr('r', '7.5');
}
```

And the structure ends up looking something like this:

```
<g class="labels">
    <!-- from ca.call(colorAxis) -->
    <g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,14.285714285714285)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
        </g>
        <!-- more of these... -->
    </g>
    <circle r="7.5" style="fill: rgb(44, 149, 210);"></circle>
    <!-- as many of these as there are ticks -->
</g>
```

And every time it calls resize, it adds even more circles (which is not what I want). What I want is a structure like this:

```
<g class="labels">
    <!-- from ca.call(colorAxis) -->
    <g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,14.285714285714285)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
            <circle r="7.5" style="fill: rgb(44, 149, 210);"></circle>
        </g>
        <!-- more of these... -->
    </g>
</g>
```

How do I fix my d3 code to achieve this? I've also tried changing `ca.selectAll('.tick').select('circle')` to `ca.selectAll('.tick')` and that caused the circles not to be appended at all.

**EDIT** I thought this was implied but apparently not. The `resize()` function is called when the DOM is resized and the axis must be adjusted accordingly to fit the content within the space allotted. The data itself is not dynamic.

Comment: Should that be `.style("fill", function (datum) {…` instead of `.style(function (datum) {…`?

Comment: Yes it should, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution offered by @Patrick is great as long as it's understood that the axis must be called and (hopefully) all of the tickmarks changed by the axis layout, between calls to `resize`.  The reason for this is that existing circles will not be deleted each time the routine is called.

Even if the axis *is* called between updates, if the number of tickmarks doesn't change - for example if only the colour encoding of the ticks changes - then the circles will build up with every update.

Using @Patricks method for this use case...

```
 function onZoom(){
    gXaxis.call(xAxis);
    var update = gXaxis.selectAll('.tick')
      .data(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0]))
      .insert('circle', "line")
      .attr('r', 7.5)
      .attr('cy',function(){return 16 + i})
      .style( "fill", function () {
        return cr();
      });
    i++;
    function cr(){
      return d3.scale.category20().range()[Math.round(Math.random()*20)]
    }
  }
```

Working demo:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, 100]),
  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.5, 3])
  .on("zoom", onZoom);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"),
  gXaxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
var i = 0;

function onZoom() {
  gXaxis.call(xAxis);
  var update = gXaxis.selectAll('.tick')
    .data(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0]))
    .insert('circle', "line")
    .attr('r', 7.5)
    .attr('cy', function() {
      return 16 + i
    })
    .style("fill", function() {
      return cr();
    });
  i++;

  function cr() {
    return d3.scale.category20().range()[Math.round(Math.random() * 20)]
  }
}
onZoom();
```

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}
.domain,
.tick line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz">
  <div>scroll to update...</div>
</div>
```

It's not that straight-forward to solve that however, and you have to add a little bit more code... not too much:

```
  function onZoom(){
    gXaxis.call(xAxis);
    var update = gXaxis
      .datum(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0]))
      .selectAll('.tick')
      .data(function(d){
        return d
      })
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(function(d){
        return [d]
      });
      update.enter().insert('circle', "line")
      .attr('r', 7.5)
      .attr('cy',function(){return 16 + i});
    update.style( "fill", function (d, i, j) {
      return cr() ;
    })
    i++;
    function cr(){
      return d3.scale.category20().range()[Math.round(Math.random()*20)]
    }
  }
```

Working demo for the same use case:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, 100]),
  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.5, 3])
  .on("zoom", onZoom);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"),
  gXaxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
var i = 0;

function onZoom() {
  gXaxis.call(xAxis);
  var update = gXaxis
    .datum(x.ticks(xAxis.ticks()[0]))
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d
    })
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(function(d) {
      return [d]
    });
  update.enter().insert('circle', "line")
    .attr('r', 7.5)
    .attr('cy', function() {
      return 16 + i
    });
  update.style("fill", function(d, i, j) {
    return cr();
  })
  i++;

  function cr() {
    return d3.scale.category20().range()[Math.round(Math.random() * 20)]
  }
}
onZoom();
```

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}
.domain,
.tick line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz">
  <div>scroll to update...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would I change it to that if the solution I posted does exactly what I want?

Comment: Because it's defensive. What happens to your version if you call `resize` with the same length of data but different data?

Comment: I just tested this and it's even worse than the scenario in my question. Not only does it not append inside the `g.tick` (it appends in the same place in my question) the data is not binded properly and all the circles are colorless.

Comment: I apologize, I was reading your answer from my phone and accidentally ran the wrong demo. However, the data for the hex codes cannot be accessed directly from the `colorAxis` and so your entire answer is predicated on the assumption that the data is dynamic, which it is not. The `resize()` method is just that: for when the DOM is resized, and it has nothing to do with change in the data itself.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, it's a really cool idea to augment the standard axese like that and that's why I took the time to investigate a general solution for your idea. The context of your particular case was not properly revealed in your OP, so your answer could easily confuse or even mislead future consumers of this question and that perspective - the perspective of the future consumer - is what I am considering. Like any declarative language, when used in novel ways like this, it's already easy enough to get confused with how d3 works, so it's good to be rigorous when sharing ideas about it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to change my code in `resize()` to:

```
function resize() {
    ca
        .call(colorAxis) // an instance of d3.svg.axis() using same data as below
        .selectAll('text')
            .remove();

    ca
        .selectAll('.tick')
            .data(data)
        .append('circle')
            .style(function (datum) {
                return '#' + datum.hex;
            })
            .attr('r', '7.5');
}
```

Comment: Your circles will be inside the `tick`s as you specify, but don't you still get extra circles each time you call `resize`?

Comment: @CoolBlue No, because `.append()` only applies for each context where a circle doesn't exist for its respective data point. Or at least that's how I understand it from reading the docs. d3 is still very confusing to me.

Comment: For that to work you need `.enter()` before `.append()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I tried that and that's what causes the circles not to be appended at all

Comment: In the future, everyone will get to understand d3 for 15 minutes. Meanwhile, take a look at my answer, I _think_ that will work?.. I didn't test it yet...

Comment: Looks like my _15 minutes_ is yet to come! :P This is more complicated than I thought because the tick g's already have data bound by the axis.  I might try again later coz its an interesting case.  Meanwhile I'll delete my wrong answer.  My comment about this answer still stands though: If you call resize twice with the same number of ticks on the axis, new circles will be added each time.

Comment: @CoolBlue that's not true because I have tested this and it always remains 1 circle per tick.

Comment: Depends on the context I guess, I tested it and it added a new one each time. As it must, because you are not deleting the previous circles and you are using enter as mentioned by Lars. We don't have much to go on since you haven't posted a working example but, the only thing I can think off is that, somewhere else in your code, you are calling the axis - which is deleting the the ticks and creating a new ones - before calling `update`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, please see my corrected answer illustrating the point.